# Funciones String Java?

Tags: java

Ayuda con una función en Java me marca error en la función **com**, no se dónde está el error o si no es posible declararlo como una función

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main

{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);

    String T1;

    String T2;

    String z;

    System.out.println("Ingrese");

    T1=entrada.nextLine();

    T2=entrada.nextLine();

        z = com(T1,T2);

System.out.println(com(T1,T2));

    }

}

public static String com(String T1,String T2){

        String x;

        if (T1.equals(T2)){

            x="Cadenas Iguales";

        }

        else{

            x="Cadenas Diferentes";

        }

        return x;

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Cuál es la pregunta o el problema?

Comment: Hay un errornen la función String

Comment: ¿Cuál es la *función string* y cuál es el error?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Tu pregunta o problema (¿?) no cuenta con la calidad suficiente ni tiene  los requisitos mínimos para ser aceptada de buena forma en la comunidad. Por favor revisa [¿Como preguntar correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) y luego edita tu pregunta

Comment: Si te refieres a esto: `public static String com(String T1,String T2){` fíjate que las variables se llaman `T1` y `T2`, luego dentro para referirte a ellas tienes que usar el mismo nombre, por ejemplo aquí: `if (texto1.equals(texto2)){` no existe en el contexto `texto1` y `texto2`, sino   `T1` y `T2` que es como están declaradas en los parámetros. O cambias el método así: `public static String com(String texto1,String texto2){`, eso es más conforme a la *convención de nombres*.

Comment: ¿Finalmente cómo tienes el código, puesto que editaste la pregunta corrigiendo el error que había? Como está ahora debería funcionar... ¿cuál es el error?

Comment: Me señala errores en las llaves {}

Comment: El error que tienes es que los métodos deben pertenecer a una clase, osea debes declararla dentro de la clase Main.

Comment: Gracias eso es....

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, puedes poner la traza del error?

Answer (score 0):

Esta poniendo afuera de la clase **Main** tu función **com** y eso es incorrecto mete el método, solo cierra el corchete de la clase **Main** hasta el final asi:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author SoftMolina
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        String T1;

        String T2;

        String z;

        System.out.println("Ingrese");

        T1 = entrada.nextLine();

        T2 = entrada.nextLine();

        z = com(T1, T2);

        System.out.println(com(T1, T2));

    }

    public static String com(String T1, String T2) {

        String x;

        if (T1.equals(T2)) {

            x = "Cadenas Iguales";

        } else {

            x = "Cadenas Diferentes";

        }

        return x;

    }

}
```

Y el resultado que me dio es el siguiente:

```
run:
Ingrese
hola
hello
Cadenas Diferentes
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo te falta meter el metodo

> com(String T1, String T2)

dentro de la clase

> Main{}

. Saludos !

Answer (score 0):

El método no debe ser declarado fuera de la clase en tu caso:

prueba así:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main

{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);

    String T1;

    String T2;

    String z;

    System.out.println("Ingrese");

    T1=entrada.nextLine();

    T2=entrada.nextLine();

        z = com(T1,T2);

System.out.println(com(T1,T2));

    }

}

public static String com(String T1,String T2){

        String x;

        if (T1.equals(T2)){

            x="Cadenas Iguales";

        }

        else{

            x="Cadenas Diferentes";

        }

        return x;

}
```

Un simple cambio al cerrar las llaves.Un saludo.